# Java callout not working on Apigee

Tags: java, jaxb, apigee, hl7-fhir

I have created an executable jar that will reads XML objects and convert it into FHIR object. This internally uses `jaxb-api.jar.` The code is compiled and even main lass is loaded when javacallout is called through Apigee. Hoever, 
I am getting error:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.inclusiveBetween(JJJLjava/lang/String;) e)
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Comment: could you solve the problem?